# How to use FLATTEN function in query function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Below in my query result:

[image: Snapshot of Google Sheets]

In the above table "Form Response" table is the response received in Google Sheets from Google Form.
I want to convert "Form Response" table to "Desired Result" Table.
I used `FLATTEN` & `SPLIT` functions to convert column `Card` data with one name in one cell.
I manually entered Timestamp date in Desired Result Table.

I need the Timestamp information automatically in Desired Table

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
={"Timestamp","Card"; 
  INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(QUERY(A2:A," where A is not null ",0)&"@",3),"@"))),
  INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(B2:B," where B is not null ",0),",")))}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)

Comment: **Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you**. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.